# How to refer to rails assets from stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I have a background image:

```
app/assets/images/bg.jpg
```

It works ok in development with the stylesheet as:

```
body {
 background: #111 url('bg.jpg') repeat-x; 
  color: #DDD;
  font: normal 90% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.2em;
}
```

But in production it doesn't show and the logs show:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bg.jpg"):
```

When I am using html and js templates I can add `.erb` to add the rails pre-processing that will let me use things like paths and helpers, e.g. `images_url`

How can I either:

a) Do a similar thing with my stylesheet

b) Use a path that works in both dev and prod.  I tried `[nothing]` and `images/` and they didn't work.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix that worked for me was to have

```
 background: #111 url('<%= image_path "bg.jpg" %>') repeat-x;
```

and name my file `.erb` as in `default.scss.css.erb`

The other approaches didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of rails, when you have a .css.scss stylesheets you have available a couple of helpers that will help you achieve that (you don't have to use .erb at all) like image-path and image-url (please take a look at the helpers section here https://github.com/rails/sass-rails)

basically what you need to do to get it working is replace

```
background: #111 url('bg.jpg') repeat-x;
```

for this

```
background: #111 image-url('bg.jpg') repeat-x;
```

and thats it. (also add the scss extension if you haven't already)

Answer (score 0):

**Precompile**

You'll want to make use of the [`asset_path_helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html), specifically `asset_url` with one of the Rails asset [preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) (SCSS / SASS)

The problem you'll have in production is that Rails appends what's known as a "[fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)" to the assets. This fingerprint serves to define the uniqueness of the precompiled files:

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.

This means that when you push to production (and by virtue, precompile) the assets, you'll end up with the "bg.png" in a totally different location than that which you're referencing in the standard file.

--

**Helpers**

The trick is to use a dynamic path helper with the preprocessors:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
body {
 background: #111 asset-url('bg.jpg') repeat-x; 
  color: #DDD;
  font: normal 90% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;
  margin-left: 1.2em;
}
```

This *should* work for you